# No se ven las fuentes de Google Fonts en mi web

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap

Buen día. Estoy desarrollando un nuevo sitio web (html5 + bootstrap) e incorporé una fuente de google font y no se ven las fuentes en mi web, intente referenciarlas tanto por el html como por el css y aún no se ven. No veo donde está el error.

mi html

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kaushan+Script" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="es/css/login-es.css">
```

Mi css

```
h1, h2, h3 {
    font-family: 'Kaushan Script', cursive;
}
```

Monte la web temporalmente [aquí](https://soyderwingmedina.com/murulu/login-es.html) para probar y se ve así

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguien tiene una idea de porque no se ven?

Comment: bootstrap si se carga después te pone un 'inherit' como font-family y vuelven a default

Comment: Wao que detalle!!! Ya cambié el orden de carga de bootstrap y se resolvió. Sumamente agradecido!

Answer (score 1):

La lectura del HTML por el navegador es de arriba hacía abajo, intenta cambiar el orden en el que llamas tus links

```
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="es/css/login-es.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kaushan+Script" rel="stylesheet">
```

Answer (score 0):

Prueba a darle un estilo dentro del HTML al H1

Ejemplo.

```
<h1 style="font-family: 'Kaushan Script', cursive;">Login</h1>
```

Puede que al estar usando Bootstrap este dando conflicto.